# Destroying a Layer with its Child in Wiengine

Tags: android

I am new to android gaming, the engine for the development that I am using is Wiengine.
I want to know how can I destroy a Layer with its child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out how to do it

this will remove children of layer
layer.removeAllChild(true);

and this will remove layer with its children 
this.removeChild(layer, true);